# How to add background color to windows (Cocoa)

Tags: cocoa

I'm making a simple application, and need a background color for the window.
I am a cocoa noob, so I need some help on how to do this?

Comment: You would have easily figured it out if you had a look at documentation or googled it once.

Comment: Actully, I did, but it did not come up with anything useful to me.

Answer (score 1):

For setting window background, use following `NSWindow` method:

```
- (void)setBackgroundColor:(NSColor *)color
```

You can look at the NSWindow documentation.
[NSWindow documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWindow_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSWindow/setBackgroundColor%3a)

Answer (score 0):

Yes vikram is right you can set the color like that below:-

```
   [yourWindow setBackgroundColor:[NSColor     
  redColor];
```

Like that you can set any color whatever you wanted here yourWindow is just an instance of  NSWindow and then using bgcolor api you can set to specified color.